# How can I find files with 7 characters (and no extension) in their names?

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I want to list files that contain only seven characters (without extensions) in their filename.

I have these files in a directory, for example:

```
1234567
bar.12
dog.cat
1234567.txt
tst.new
big.tst
abcdefg
abcd.efg
```

I want to list files using the command `ls` to find file names without extensions that have exactly 7 characters. I want the output to look something like this:

```
$ ls <some kind of code>
1234567
abcdefg
```

I prefer not to use any globs of any sort, or the `find` command.

Comment: you want to **not** use find, and **not** use wildcards? o.O

Comment: yeah...pretty much. is that possible? @Zanna

Comment: I very much doubt it...

Comment: Then what would be the answer with globs and the find command included? @Zanna

Comment: Sorry I'm new to using unix and bash... My professor usually restricts using globs on the exams but thank you so much for the help! :) @Zanna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sort-of solution with shell wildcards (exactly 7 characters that are not `.`)

```
ls [!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]
```

And here's a solution with `find` using regex negation (not literal `.` = `[^\.]`) and specifying how many characters `{7}`

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./[^.]{7}'
```

Not what you asked for, but I doubt it can be done without some kind of wildcards or regex.

Comment: the first solution is actually perfect! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Always a pleasure @YoosoLee :)

Comment: `find ... -name "???????" ! -name "*.*"` should also do

Comment: @ilkkachu nice one - you could post it as an answer, if you want to

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
 for f in ??????? ; do 
     [[ $f = *.* ]] && continue; 
     echo $f ;                     # do something useful here
 done
```

With `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "???????" ! -name "*.*"
```

Though since you asked for it without globs or find and used the word "professor", they maybe looking for `ls | grep ...`. But see also [a couple of reasons to avoid using `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for this.

Answer (score 1):

With extended globs in `zsh`:

```
% ls
1234567  1234567.txt  abcdefg  abcd.efg  bar.12  big.tst  dog.cat  tst.new
```

then

```
% setopt extended_glob
% ls (?~.)(#c7)
1234567  abcdefg
```

- `?~.` any character except `.`
- `(#c7)` a globbing flag equivalent to regular expression quantifier `{7}`

See [zsh: 14 Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)